# Disqus SSO integration on website

Tags: single-sign-on, disqus

We're including in our website the SSO feature on Disqus. 
Following the Disqus documentation here http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768 and here http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206

We put our login button in place, and once a user is already logged in in our site he is able to comment with his personal nickname.

As displayed, and already mentioned above, by this image in the article http://content.disqus.com/docs/sso-button.png

We see our button correctly (as the IGN one), but what we would like to do is to remove the other 4 buttons below (Facebook, Twitter, Google and Disqus) in order to permit our users to login only with our system. Do you think is it possible ? 
I saw Disqus 2012 widget integration in http://www.npr.com website and their implementation of SSO looks like exactly how we'd like to do it.

Many thanks for you support in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question directly, there's no way to remove the other login options. NPR and IGN have an implementation which isn't available to any other site. That said we're working on a feature that will address the "SSO-only" concerns so we can even phase them out of using this barrier.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, do you think NPR has an implementation made by themself or it is something done with Disqus team?

Comment: Hi Ryan - nearly 2 years later - is this still the same answer? No way to remove the non-SSO logins?

Comment: NM - Looks like I found the answer in this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305866/how-to-enable-only-login-from-my-site-and-disable-other-social-login-options-in?rq=1 - still not removable

Comment: 5 years later and no progress on this issue?