# Disqus Comment Using Login of my website

Tags: disqus

I am planning to use DISQUS comments in my portal.

It provides comments through FB,TWEETER, WOrdpress and DISQUS login I want my users to post comments also if they are logged in my website and not of all above.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Ive not done it but this seems to suggest you can create an API Key for your application and acheive what you need through OAuth (possibly) heres what I think is the relevant API Doc page http://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disqus SSO integration on website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951076/disqus-sso-integration-on-website)

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for **Single-Sign On**:

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-single-sign-on

It is an add-on only available with a Pro level subscription. The above article walks through the process in detail, complete with code examples in multiple languages.

It appears that you *cannot* remove the other sign-in options, see this SO thread:

[Disqus SSO integration on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951076/disqus-sso-integration-on-website)

Comment: Seems like now its a free feature. "Access to Single Sign-On (SSO) is currently available as a free add-on for your Disqus account"

Comment: outdated now. says "Access to Single Sign-On (SSO) is currently available as an add-on for users with a Pro level subscription."