# Disqus with SSO and social logins for site

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, disqus

I've got a website with Disqus comments and Disqus SSO enabled.

I want my users to log in to my site via site itself (with login\passwords) and via social networks (e.g. Google, Twitter)

After user logins, he(she) will take advantage of using custom bookmarks system and leave comment via Disqus.

User has two places where to login:

1. via site 'login' button accepting both username/passwords and social networks
2. via Disqus comments login system.

When user logs in via site (case 1) Disqus comments automatically log in user as well (creating separate account for this user as discribed in SSO documentation)

**The problem is** - when user logs in via Disqus comments (e.g. via Facebook login) **the site can't recognize this user** - thinking that user is anonymous.

1. Can I somehow hook to Disqus login process, so when user logs in via Disqus he/she in the same moment login to my site?

*(actual only for social apps, worked fine with in site 'SSO Disqus button' login)*

*(remember, there are different 'Applications' used by My Site and Disqus login to e.g.  Facebook App, so it's practically different users. It's better to merge them somehow...)*

2. Can I completly disable login via Disqus module

*(like on this site: http://www.npr.org/)*

*(two years old link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964157)*

*PS: I use django as framework, django-registration and python-social-auth for in site registration/login.*