# How to enable only login from my site and disable other social login options in DISQUS?

Tags: single-sign-on, disqus

I have enabled DISQUS SSO for my site. But I want to enable only login from my site and disable other social login options in DISQUS login dropdown options?

Answer (score 7):

**Elements that can't be edited or removed**

- Disqus logo
- **Social login buttons (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Disqus)**
- Community tab (your site name at the top of the embed)
- Font size
- Voting, sharing, and favorite star buttons
- "Add Disqus to your site" text
- "# Comments" text above the embed (For home page comment counts, see
  Adding comment count links to your home page)
- "Join the Discussion" text

Source : https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. I have an idea of the concept but don't know how to implement it though, but there are sites that did it.

I saw sites like Osu! that treats non logged-in users like it as an anonymous profile. I think it's a way to avoid disqus comment system from displaying a login button.

Here's a sample of their page with disqus.
https://osu.ppy.sh/b/83392

I wonder how to do something like that.

Comment: They are just auto logging in a "anonymous_old" user using disqus API if the site user is not logged in, they have also blocked the user from posting, therefore it doesn't allow 'anonymous_old' to post anything. But this approach just confuses the visitor, like "Why am I logged in as anonymous_old?", "Why are they not allowing me to post comment?" etc